# How to get Bpm with 4 heart beat pulses

Tags: sensors

I'm trying to get an average from three intervals to get bpm. However, when I use the code below the bpm would slowly decrease when used with the sensor. Can anyone please check for what is wrong with the code and for reference I have to modify the below code from the link for 4 beats to get bpm. [Getting BPM from the given code](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/43956/getting-bpm-from-the-given-code)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29);

//global variables

int  ibeats, iInterval1, iInterval2, iInterval3, iCount = 1;
unsigned long iFirstPulse, iSecondPulse, iThirdPulse, iFourthPulse;
bool bIgnoreread = false;
bool bFirstPulse = false, bSecondPulse = false, bThirdPulse = false, bFourthPulse = false;

float BPM, fAverage;

void setup()
{
  //initialize USB serial port, I2C bus and LCD
  Serial.begin(115200);         //set this comm up in-case you want to troubleshoot

  lcd.begin(20, 4); delay(2);
  lcd.clear(); delay(2);

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0); lcd.print(" Patient Prober");


}

void loop()
{

  ibeats = analogRead(15); delay(5);//  Read the Pulse Sensor's value.

  lcd.setCursor(0, 3); lcd.print("BPM:"); lcd.print(BPM); lcd.print(" ");// displaying bpm value on LCD

  if (ibeats > 780 && bIgnoreread == false)     //once the signal is high and bIgnoread is false inital condition, inside if statment will start
  {
    if (bFirstPulse == false && iCount == 1) 
    {
      iFirstPulse = millis();   // time when the pulse is high for the FirstPulse
      bFirstPulse = true;      // to turn off if statement 
    }

    if (bSecondPulse == false && iCount == 2)
    {
      iSecondPulse = millis();
      iInterval1 = iSecondPulse - iFirstPulse;   // first interval
      bSecondPulse = true;
    }

    if (bThirdPulse == false && iCount == 3)
    {
      iThirdPulse = millis();
      iInterval2 = iThirdPulse - iSecondPulse;    //Second Interval
      bThirdPulse = true;
    }

    if (bFourthPulse == false && iCount == 4)
    {
      iFourthPulse = millis();
      iInterval3 = iFourthPulse - iThirdPulse;    // third interval
      bFourthPulse = true;
    }

    bIgnoreread = true; // to turn off when millis second is assign to variable Pulse  When the signal is high
  }

  // reseting all the bollean to intial condition
  if (ibeats < 300)
  {
    bIgnoreread = false;
    bFirstPulse = false;
    bSecondPulse = false;
    bThirdPulse = false;
    bFourthPulse = false;
    iCount++;               // incrment to help to diffrent if ststment above
  }

  //if(ibeats==0)iCount++;

  fAverage = ( iInterval1 + iInterval2 + iInterval3) / 3;         // Average for the interval
  BPM = (60000.0 / fAverage);                                    // Bpm calculation

  if (iCount > 4)iCount = 1;                                    // reseting icount to start the cycle again
}
//********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: your sketch contains no debugging code ... add some ... you cannot pinpoint the problem without it

Comment: you don't need to know when the second and third pulses occur ... get the timestamp of first pulse ... detect second pulse and third pulse ... calculate the BPM using the 1st and the 4th pulses

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to implement a *rolling average* for this. You want the average time of the previous four beats, (or rather the previous three time intervals), and each time you get a new interval you "forget" the oldest and add the newest, calculating the average of the three you have each time.